# Configure IIS 6 web application on a personal server

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, iis-6

A group of us wrote a .NET web application for our University class and in order to let our prof test with it I am setting it up on my webserver at home.  Here is what I have done so far:

I created a new account on my domain, I then granted that account Read, write access to the folder where the app is stored.  I have setup an application pool that uses this new account as its identity and created a new site that uses the new application pool.

I initially was receiving the Service unavailable error message, so I realized I had to add my account to the IIS_WPG account.  So now I am stuck at the "page cannot be found".  The website is pointing to the correct folder (I can see the aspx page list from within the IIS browser) but when browsing the site either in IIS, on a browser on the server or on a browser within my network I keep getting Page cannot be found.  The home directory is pointing to default.aspx which is what our app uses.

The app of course works just fine when running from within the IDE, but now that I am trying to get it to work it doesn't want to.

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the issue.  What I didn't know is that by default, IIS 6 does not turn on support of active server pages and .NET pages in Web Service Extensions.  Once I had turned this on the site began to work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

you should give error details first.

for now, I suggest you check the 'network service' account's permission.this is the ASP.NET's account.
 then publish your site to *.aspx file and *.dll file. to see if there is any errors.

Comment: No error message beyond what I indicated above.  I have since tried the following: Removed my app from the folder that it was contained in and replaced it with a basic .htm page.  This worked fine, but as soon as I put my application back in, I get the Page cannot be found message.

Comment: @HawkeyeD try amend IIS .net framework version to 2.0 or above